# Selenium firefox fails to load only when run through windows task scheduler

Tags: python, windows, selenium, firefox

I have a web scraping script in Python, using Selenium and (tor) Firefox. This runs completely fine when I start the script manually, in my IDE or from cmd. However, this script needs to be run when I am not in the office, so I run it via a batch script (along with some other scraping scripts) which is started by the windows task scheduler. Again, when I run this batch file manually, the script runs perfectly. When the scheduled task runs, on the other hand, it fails as soon as the webdriver is set with the following unhelpful error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  #private library traceback
  ...
  File "redacted.py", line 322, in redacted_func
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error occurs *only when run from the task scheduler?*

Comment: Are you running the scheduled task as a different user?

Comment: The task is being run as the same user that can successfully run the process manually.

Answer (score 3):

After further investigation, I found that the error happens when the task is processed in the background. This happens when the task is set to 'Run whether user is logged on or not'. Changing this setting to 'Run only when user is logged on' allows the task to run without issue, in the foreground.

For some reason, running in the background causes firefox to crash, but chromedriver (which is used in some other scraping scripts I run) is unaffected by this. This seems slightly bizarre, but this workaround is sufficient to get this running on windows.

Comment: Setting up the 'Run only when user is logged on' does work, but then you miss the point of running the scheduled task automatically since you need a user to actually be logged on to the server when the scheduled task is supposed to run

Comment: I fail to see how this misses the point? You either need a bugfix, so that firefox runs in the background without error (which I can't help you with) or log in a user to run the task interactively. You still get to run the task whenever you like, which is after all, the point of the task scheduler...