# Selenium Firefox Webdriver doesn't run when launched through a scheduled task with option "Run whether user is logged on or not""

Tags: selenium, firefox

I would like to execute tests using Selenium WebDriver with a variety of browsers (at least Firefox and Chrome). In order to run these tests regularly, I created a scheduled task which launches a simple command:

```
node screenshot.js >log.txt 2>&1
```

Where screenshot.js is:

```
var webdriver   = require('selenium-webdriver'),
...
// Import drivers here
...
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');

driver.takeScreenshot().then(
    function(image, err) {
        require('fs').writeFile('out.jpg', image, 'base64', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
);

driver.quit();
```

If I run the scheduled task with the option "Run only when user is logged on", everything wells well and the screenshot is saved. If however I configure the task with "Run whether user is logged in or not" it doesn't.
Interesting note is that if I replace "firefox" with "chrome" in my script, the screenshot is correctly is saved in both cases.

The only reference to this issue that I found was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283428/2847079 but it doesn't provide any solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the asker/answerer of the referenced issue:

Try the workaround. Change the task to run only when the user is logged in, and leave the user logged in at all times - which was a good enough solution for me, since the machine I ran the task on did nothing else.

I realise that this is less than optimal solution, so perhaps you can work out some separate task to do the logging in and out at the appropriate times before and after you run your main task. See this question which explains how to go about this: https://superuser.com/questions/616206/run-interactive-task-even-if-user-is-not-logged-on-windows

An option that was not available to me - but may be to you - is to not run the task on windows. Windows (somewhat bafflingly) forces you to be logged in *a priori* to run an interactive task, but you *should* be able to run firefox interactively in linux with a cronjob without being logged in.

Unfortunately for you (but very fortunately for me!) I no longer work at the company where this environment/code problem arose, so I can't test the above suggestions.

At any rate, I suggest you submit a bug report to the selenium project, as there doesn't appear to be a proper solution at present - though happy to be proven wrong.